# Is there a Julia equivalent to numpy.digitize?

Tags: julia

Given a bin range `min:step:max` and a value `x` I want to find the bin the `x` is in. Is there a better way than

`floor(Int, (x-min)/step)`

?

Comment: That seems like a pretty good way. You will have to add 1 to that if you want to store it in a standard array.

Answer (score 3):

`searchsortedfirst(min:step:max, x)` does what you need. The first bin is for values less than `min` and the last for greater than `max` (and it is implemented efficiently due to multiple dispatch)